# My php sendmail script stopped working automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, email, sendmail

need your help, my website form stopped working from yesterday morning. The same code was working from last 3 years.
Website is - https://www.dlfhomes.co.in/dlf-gardencity-enclave-floors-sector-93-gurgaon/

```
<?php
$sendto   = "milestone.kamal@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$project = $_POST['project'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

$subject  = "".$project." Enquiry";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>".$project." Enquiry</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Full Name:</strong> ".$name."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Mobile No:</strong> ".$mobile."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Email:</strong> ".$email."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Project:</strong> ".$project."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>City:</strong> ".$city."</p>\r\n";

$msg .= "</body></html>";
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "Thank You!";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

Comment: Website is https://www.dlfhomes.co.in/

Comment: Check the server logs. Check the SMTP provider logs.

Answer (score -1):

if the code has been running for 3 years, then it might not be a code issue but more likely an issue with the configuration of your server

try to access the server hosting the website and check the logs (tail /var/log/maillog if linux)

also, you can check the php logs in the /var/log/httpd/error_log